# Horizontal bars across my screen on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, 20.04, intel-graphics, screen, gpu-driver

I recently changed my OS from windows 10 to linux 20.04 LTS. When I boot with `nomodeset` I have no issue but in without the `nomodeset`, there are horizontal lines across screen that are constantly blinking and moving one place to other (horizontal roving lines). I have intel pentium g630 processor with integrated Intel HD graphics 4 gb ram. How can I fix it?

I can confirm this is not a hardware issue since currently I am using windows 10 and it is working fine.

So far I have tried installing

- Ubuntu 18.04.06 Lts
- Xubuntu (using `sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop` and `xfec4`)
- Linux Mint

I tried removing Intel drivers and rebooting but no change.
Reinstalling intel drivers also had no effect.

[Video of the error](https://youtu.be/GcAXAicoZqY)

[Here is my youtube channel where I have uploaded 3 videos showing this issue](https://youtube.com/@theawesomes1440)

Comment: Please do not add additional info as comments edit and add it to the question.

Comment: *I can confirm this is not a hardware issue since bios screen is perfect and nomodeset works fine* **Unlike what you think, this doesn't means there isn't an hardware problem**, neither BIOS screen or the generic VESA graphics mode that you get when using `nomodeset` uses the full graphics resources/features, all the opposite. Only why a desktop environment and proper drivers loaded the graphics can be used to its full potential and that's when problems may show up.

Comment: I would like to tell you that I have been using windows 10 but it works perfectly fine...

Comment: If I reinstall windows 10 it still works fine